# Can I use the Steam client as a launcher for all my games?

Tags: steam

On Windows the Steam client allows me to link non Steam games so that I can use the client as a launcher for all my games in my system.

Can that be done also in the Linux client for my Wine / PlayonLinux games? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Wine or PlayOnLinux games provide a launcher, then it should work as in Windows. As an example, adding Mahjongg to the Steam games list:

[image]

All the applications that appear on the Dash should be listed here. If the launcher is not on the list, one can use the "Browse" button to locate it (using wine they should be located in `~/.local/share/applications/wine`). Unfortunately it seems "Browse" only let you select .desktop files, so if your application don't have one you need to create it.

[image]

After the selection, the game should appear on the list:

[image]

Comment: Will it list Wine installed games? Can you show an example of that instead of a system installed game?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have any game installed (using Wine) to test. But i do have some personal launchers defined in `~/.local/share/applications/personal` and they appear on the list. So the Wine ones should appear as well.